# Ajax output brings duplicate PHP upload form on web page

Tags: php, ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

I'm trying to integrate a progress bar available at http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html into a php upload form. It works well except it returns duplicate upload form on the same page after submitting the first form. See the screen shots of form below.

[Form Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ0BH.png)

The ajax call is following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');


$('#Myform').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function() {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {

        status.html(xhr.responseText);

    }
}); 

})();
```

html part can be represented as:

```
<form id="#Myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="DocFile"/>
<input type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload"/>
</form>

<div class="progress">
<div class="bar"></div >
<div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>
<div id="status"></div>
```

I store form validation messages in PHP array and output these to a predefined div in my upload script.

`xhr.responseText`outputs the PHP validation messages in `#status` div but it causes the appearance of duplicate form as per the attached screen shot.

Any idea whats going wrong here?

Comment: can you please show your html code?

Comment: i edited my question. you can see html part there.

Comment: `<form id="#Myform"` remove '#'

Comment: and you have not ended your </form> tag

Comment: that was a typo.. I don't store #Myform in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP-Function is (based on `action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"`) on the same page as your other html (also your upload form amongst other). The AJAX-Functionality basically just loads the linked file with the form parameters and uses the whole content after the PHP execution as the result. In you case, the content includes your response but also your form.

Now how to solve this problem? The easiest way would be, to define your PHP in another file and link to that. For that, add `action="upload.php"` to your `<form>`-Tag. Then create a new PHP-File:

upload.php

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    ...
    echo "47";
}
```

Comment: Won't that cause prevent outputting `responseText` which ultimately cause stop outputting PHP validation message? In developer view I see that, at present the ajax call starts at '<body><div id="status"></div></body>' passes to '<html><html/>' and then returns to '<body><div id="status"></div></body>' through `responseText` along with duplicate form and progress bar nested in the same div. It seems that `responseText` returns the duplicate of the form and progress bar.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I didn't noticed that the second form appears only after submission of the first form. In that case, could you provide your PHP-Code?

Comment: I think I found your issue: Look my updated answer up

Comment: `xhr.responseTex`t can't make any output that way. I guess there may be any predefined function, option or attribute  to handle this sort of issue. I see that `JSON` is commonly used to output  'PHP` validation in this type case though i'm looking for javascript or ajax solution for it..

Comment: Still the ajax response starts at `<body><div id="status"></div></body>`  after initiated by the `form` element, passes to `<html><html/>`  and then returns to `<body><div id="status"></div></body>`  through `xmlhttp` `responseText` along with duplicate form and progress bar nested in the same div.